# What is the best way to Show a Correlation Matrix as a Cluster/Network Graph in Python?

Tags: data-visualization, python, correlation-matrix

I'm struggling because while I want to show the interrelationship of correlation between my fields, I realize that trying to plot nodes in terms of distance away from each other based on correlation will lead to impossibilities such as a case where A and B are 1 unit apart, B and C are 1 unit apart, but C and A are say, 5 units apart, there is no way to represent this on a 2 dimensional plane.

I simply want to create a visualization that generally clusters things with high correlation together, and moves things that are anti-correlated apart. So far, the closest I've gotten is using python networkx:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()

for ii in range(len(links_filtered)):
    a = data['var1'][ii]
    b = data['var2'][ii]
    c = data['value'][ii]
    G.add_edge(a,b,length=c,weight=c)

elarge = [(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight']>0]
esmall = [(u,v) for (u,v,d) in G.edges(data=True) if d['weight']<=0]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G,k=.2,iterations=10000)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,pos,node_color='orange',node_size=400)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=elarge,edge_color='blue')
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,pos,edgelist=esmall,edge_color='red',alpha=0.5,style='dashed')
# nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,pos,font_size=8,)

for k,v in pos.iteritems():
    x,y = pos[k]
    plt.text(x,y,k,bbox=dict(facecolor='white',alpha=0.8),horizontalalignment='center',verticalalignment='baseline',fontsize=8,color='black')
```

However, the result is generally ugly, and doesn't actually ensure that clusters that are not correlated are not in close proximity, since it is only drawing edges, not actually calcing a distance between nodes.[image]

Comment: I see a few off-topic close votes, but I think there is an interesting data viz question here if you take away the Python aspect: is there a good way to visualize correlation as a node graph?

Comment: This is too subjective to opinion, I suggest narrowing down the question a bit further.